# Folder doesn't show up in explorer, cmd, and python even though I can access it, how can I fix this?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, network-shares, ntfs

I am accessing another computer on the network using a mapped network drive.  The path looks like \\192.168.0.100\d$ which is mapped to my computer's "m" drive.  I can access, view, create, delete, move, etc folders on this drive.  However, some folders don't show up in windows explorer, even tho I can access them.

Example:

Lets say that **M:\stuff\more_stuff** is a directory.

What I can't do:

- When windows explorer is pointed at **M:\stuff**  I can't see **more_stuff**
- In cmd prompt pointed at **M:\stuff** "dir" doesn't find **more_stuff**
- In cmd prompt pointed at **M:\stuff** "dir /a" doens't find **more_stuff**
- In python, os.listdir at **M:\stuff** doens't find **more_stuff**

What I can do:

- Typing **M:\stuff\more_stuff** into the address bar lets me access the folder like normal.

Because there is no indication that this folder even exists, there could be more like them.  I have no way of knowing how many folders are magically hidden on this mapped drive.

What are some steps I can do to figure out why this folder is hidden? (With the end goal of making it no longer hidden).

Originally posted on server fault https://serverfault.com/questions/433735/folder-doesnt-show-up-in-explorer-cmd-and-python-even-though-i-can-access-it

**EDIT New info**

When I log into the machine itself I can see all of these folders just fine.
When I disconnect and reconnect the mapped drive, the folders show up.  So it definitely has something to do with the mapped drive.

Comment: For future reference, please don't cross-post questions. If you accidentally post a question on the wrong Stack Exchange website, you should be able to flag the question and ask a moderator to move it to the correct site.

Comment: Was **more_stuff** created or renamed recently?  It is conceivable that your computer cached a copy of **M:\stuff** when you mapped the drive, and that stale cached copy never got updated.

Comment: Yes **more_stuff** was created recently.  I'd like to figure out whats causing the issue since users are reporting that it happens frequently.  Most likely **more_stuff** was created by a script running on the same machine with the same credentials as the user running windows explorer.  If it does have something to do with a cached copy, is there some way to force a refresh?